# How to get key name of array with number in range list?

Tags: php

How to find key name, or list name, if value is in range of list.

```
<?php
$list = [
'block-1'=>"1000-2000",
'block-2'=>"2001-5000"
];

$block = getBlockByNum(3015);
// It should give block-2

?>
```

Is their any fast way to find the block name by a number within range.

Without looping each array key/value.
PS, It doesn't need to be an array, The concept is to get a name of block, by a number. Each block has a range specified. I want to know which range and block the number reside.

Thanks.

Comment: Without looping - no way.

Comment: Feel free to use array functions such as f.e. array_filter, if you want to avoid having to _explicitly_ write loops yourself.

Comment: Is their any alternative way for the same, Like in MySQL we can use BETWEEN. Any fast way to find which set the key is on. Each set has a fixed range.

Comment: Do you have any rational reason not to use a loop? They are simple, readable and performant.. and as CBroe indicates, functional methods such as `array_walk` will still use loops under the hood

Comment: @Kaddath, Their is not an specific reason, But the list may go large, So just looking if their is something else that is capable of Finding a set name from group of sets by a number. Each set consist of a specific range [positive numbers].

Comment: If you go into the details of the operations, you realize there is no way to decide which item(s) will fit if you don't look at them one by one, even MySQL does it. You shouldn't worry about the size of your list, computers nowadays are fast, you may be surprised how quick it will be. It is called premature optimization, and should be avoided, begin to worry about such things when you notice something is slow, not before.